# Reversing a string in C using Visual Studio

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, reverse

I'm building a program for reversing a string in visual studio, and while I run the code and enter a word I want to reverse, the program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(void) {
    char r[256];
    int i, d;
    printf("\nEnter the word you want to reverse : ");
    gets_s(" %s", r, sizeof(r));
    d = strlen(r);
    for (i=d;i!=0;i--) {
        printf("%s",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to print `r[i]`, not `i`...And not with this format specifier.

Comment: `gets_s(" %s", r, sizeof(r));` --> `gets_s(r, sizeof(r));`

Comment: `for (i=d-1;i>=0;i--) {
        printf("%c",r[i]);
    }`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, both was wrong in my code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that I tried your program on Linux, so no MS Visual C++ and more specifically no `conio.h` and `gets_s`.

There are multiple problems with your program:

Your call to `gets_s` is incorrect, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7.aspx) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), `gets_s` is defined as:

```
char *gets_s( 
  char *buffer,
  size_t sizeInCharacters
);
```

You are calling it with illegal arguments. Instead of `gets_s(" %s", r, sizeof(r));` you need to call it like this:

```
gets_s(r, 256);
```

the first parameter is pointer to the string buffer where the `gets_s` function will store the line from input and the second is the size of the buffer, note that in `char r[256]` you can store 255 characters and terminating zero (`\0`).

Your for loop is incorrect instead of `for (i=d;i!=0;i--) {` you need to do it like this:

```
for (i=d-1;i>=0;i--) {
```

now the loop starts from last character instead of `\0` and ends when the `i < 0` ie. the last print will be when `i=0`.

And your final mistake is that you are using `printf` incorrectly instead of `printf("%s",i);` you need to do:

```
printf("%c",r[i]);
```

because you are printing characters: `"%c"` is for `char` output and `r[i]` is i-th character from string `r` (don't forget that we count from 0).

So, in total this is how the program should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> // does not exist on GCC (Linux)
#include <string.h>

main(void) {
    char r[256]; // 255 characters + \0
    int i, d;
    printf("\nEnter the word you want to reverse : ");
    gets_s(r, 256); // store at most 255 characters + \0 
                    // does not work on GCC (Linux) even with -std=C11
    d = strlen(r);

    // start from last character and include first
    for (i=d-1;i>=0;i--) {
        // %c - character, r[i] gets the i-th character from string r
        printf("%c",r[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void rev(char *s)
{
    char *start, *end;

    end = start + strlen(s) - 1;
    for (start = s; end > start; ++start, --end) {
        char tmp;

        tmp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = tmp;
    }
}
```

Use the `fgets` function, and also put the reversing code in its own function, like I did. So the final code is

```
int main()
{
    char line[80];

    fgets(line, 80, stdin);
    /* don't allow empty string */
    if (*line == '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "Empty string is not a string\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* remove the \n placed by fgets */
    remnl(line);
    rev(line);
    printf("%s\n", line);

    return 0;
}
void remnl(char *s) { s[strlen(s) - 1] = 0; }
```

Comment: `char* end = strlen(s) - 1;`?? And don't ignore the `newline` put by `fgets` at the end of the string.

Comment: fixed it @WeatherVane

Comment: remnl identifier not found

Comment: move the `remnl` function above `main`.

Comment: This will fail to trap the empty string and cause *undefined behaviour*, both in the attempt to remove a `newline`, and the setting of `end` which will not be a valid pointer in this case, being potentially "less than" `s`.

Comment: fixed it @WeatherVane

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    char r[256];
    int i, d;
    printf("\nEnter the word you want to reverse : ");
    gets_s(r, sizeof(r));
    d = strlen(r) - 1;
    for (i = d; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", r[i]);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed `gets` is no longer in the standard C library. Even with older compilers, it should not be used, and it is not a recommended solution.